# Subversion with Mac OS X

Tags: svn, macos

I'm using the built in SVN with Mac OS X and  I checked out a project via command line. I got all my projects and everything but the .svn folder wasn't created like it was on my PC. And now SVN is just treating my project like a folder and I can't do updates or anything. Any ideas?

.svn is not a valid folder name for Mac

Comment: Did you create your projects, by `svn co`?  If not, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.svn` certainly is a valid folder name on OS X. However, because it starts with a dot, `ls` will hide it by default. Try `ls -a` and see whether it shows up.

Comment: The MacOS X finder also hides dotfiles by default -- you can make them visible with third-party utilities like TinkerTool.

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of an svn st on the project directory on the local filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you did export instead of check out?